# Display HTML table on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to display URL response into a table when the page loads. But I could oly be able to console URL response but not display them into a table.Here is my js file:

```
window.onload  = function (){
    var result = $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url:  "http://localhost:8080/impExt",
        dataType:"json", //to parse string into JSON object,
        success: function(data){
            if(data){
                var len = data.length;
                var txt = "";
                if(len > 0){
                    for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
                        if(data[i].name && data[i].ext){
                            txt += "<tr><td>"+data[i].name+"</td><td>"+data[i].ext+"</td></tr>";
                            console.log(txt);
                        }
                    }
                    if(txt != ""){
                        $("#impExtTableID tbody").html(txt).removeClass("hidden");
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert('error: ' + textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
        }
    }).responseText;
    return false;//suppress natural form submission
};
```

I have tried several answers related to my post but nothing works. Can someone help me in displaying this table on page load? If you need my index page by any chance, here it is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:margin-right="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:padding-bottom="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:width="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head></head>

<body>
    <table  id = "impExtTableID" class= "hidden"  >
        <thead style="width:03%">
            <th style="width:60%">Name</th>
            <th style="width:22%">Ext</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>

    <script src = "js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src ="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src = "js/impExt.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hidden` class needs to be removed from `table`, not `tbody`. Make it

```
 $("#impExtTableID tbody").html(txt);
 $("#impExtTableID").removeClass("hidden");
```

Comment: It worked, but the headers disappeared. I want the headers as well to be displayed. Can you also tell me the reason for having those two lines?
$("#impExtTableID tbody").html(txt);
 $("#impExtTableID").removeClass("hidden");

Comment: Reason for having two lines is to ensure that you remove hidden class from table rather than tbody.

Comment: what should I do to keep the headers in the table?